# My Unity Hub doesn't go past the loading screen on mac

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to download the Unity Hub for a school project on my macbook. I have a macbook pro with macOS Montery version 12.6. Every time i try to download it, it seems to work during the entire download process, until i try to start the program. I click on the program in my launchpad and the window with the logo and the loading icon. Then it keeps stuck on that screen. I have added a screenshot of that window.

Please help :)

[Screenshot loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mvqi.png)

Comment: maybe pos this on unity firmus too and submit a bug report

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it by reinstalling it, but I needed to do a deeper uninstall to make it work.
You can follow [this](https://www.imymac.com/powermymac/how-to-uninstall-unity-on-mac.html#:%7E:text=Open%20Funter%20and%20type%20in,Trash%20and%20reboot%20the%20Mac.) one to help you.